# Помогите разбить на функции программу на C++

Tags: c++, функции

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    system("mode con cols=200 lines=200");

    int N, sum = 0, min = 0, sum_el_mat = 0, sum_el_mat2 = 0;

    cout << "Введите  натруальное число  N" << endl;
    cin >> N;

    if (N > 0 && N % 1 == 0  )
        // Проверка на дробность  
    {
        cout << "" << endl;
        int **ptrarray = new int*[N + 15];

        for (int counter = 0; counter < N + 15; counter++)
            ptrarray[counter] = new int[N + 15];
        // Заполняем массив
        for (int count_row = 0; count_row < N + 15; count_row++)
        for (int count_column = 0; count_column < N + 15; count_column++)
        {
            ptrarray[count_row][count_column] = rand() % ((15 + N) * 2 + 1) - 15 - N;
            cout << ptrarray[count_row][count_column] << setw(5);
            // Выводим елементы массива
        }

        cout << "  " << endl;

        for (int count_row = 0; count_row < N + 15; count_row++)
        {
            for (int count_column = 0; count_column < N + 15; count_column++)
                sum = ptrarray[count_row][count_column] + sum;
            //Сумма элементов массива
        }

        cout << "  " << endl;
        cout << " Сумма элементов массива = " << sum << endl;

        for (int count_row = 0; count_row < N + 15; count_row++)
        {
            for (int count_column = 0; count_column < N + 15; count_column++)
            {
                if (min > ptrarray[count_row][count_column])
                    min = ptrarray[count_row][count_column];
            }
            // Нахождение мниимального элемента;
        }

        cout << " Наименьший елемент = " << min << endl;

        int Mmin = abs(min);
        // Абсолютное значение min элемента

        for (int count_row = 0; count_row < N + 15; count_row++)
        {
            for (int count_column = 0; count_column < N + 15; count_column++)
            {
                ptrarray[count_row][count_column] = pow(ptrarray[count_row][count_column], 2);
                sum_el_mat = ptrarray[count_row][count_column] + sum_el_mat;
                //Сумма квадратов 1 матрицы 
            }
        }

        cout << " Сумма квадратов 1 матрицы  = " << sum_el_mat << endl;

        for (int count_row = 0; count_row < N + 15; count_row++)
        {
            for (int count_column = 0; count_column < N + 15; count_column++)
            {
                ptrarray[count_row][count_column] = (sqrt(ptrarray[count_row][count_column]) + Mmin) * (sqrt(ptrarray[count_row][count_column]) + Mmin);
                sum_el_mat2 = ptrarray[count_row][count_column] + sum_el_mat2;
                //Сумма квадратов 2 матрицы ( с прибавленным наименьшим елементом) 
            }
        }

        cout << " Сумма квадратов 2 матрицы ( с прибавленным наименьшим елементом)   = " << sum_el_mat2 << endl;
        system("pause");
    }
    else {
        cout << "Ошибка, вы ввели не натуральное число" << endl;
        system("pause");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Дана матрица (N+15)x(N+15); найти сумму всех чисел матрицы. Найти минимальный элемент и прибавить его абсолютное значение к каждому элементу матрицы. Рассчитать сумму квадратов для обеих матриц, числа генерировать случайно в интервале [-N-15; N+15]

Comment: Вы хотя бы написали, что программа делает.

Comment: К примеру, что означает это глубокомысленное условие в предложении if?  if (N > 0 && N % 1 == 0  )

Comment: `N % 1`, о боже.

Comment: Проверяет число больше 0, а второе - проверяет число дробное или нет

Comment: @Валерий: Позвольте поинтересоваться, какого типа переменная `N`?

Comment: Дана матрица (N+15)x(N+15) найти сумму всех чисел матрица. Найти минимальный элемент и прибавить его абсолютное значение к каждому элементу матрицы. Рассчитать сумму квадратов для обеих матриц, числа генерировать случайно в интервале [-N-15; N+15]

Comment: Она имееет  тип int

Comment: @Валерий А в чем смысл этого магического числа 15? Почему, к примеру, не 10?

Comment: Дана матрица (N+15)x(N+15) найти сумму всех чисел матрица. Найти минимальный элемент и прибавить его абсолютное значение к каждому элементу матрицы. Рассчитать сумму квадратов для обеих матриц, числа генерировать случайно в интервале [-N-15; N+15]

Comment: По условию так сказано

Comment: @Валерий Если 15 - это минимальное число элементов в размерности матрицы, то почему N не быть равным 0? Почему N обязательно должно быть больше 0?

Comment: Имеется ввиду, что N - это натуральное

Comment: Если `N` имеет тип `int`, зачем проверять его на дробность? Как оно может быть при этом дробным?

Comment: Согласно правилам сообщества вопросы не должны сводиться к завершению задач за учащихся. Приведите пример вашей реализации и задайте вопрос с описанием конкретных проблем.

Answer (score 4):

Условие в данном предложении `if`

```
 if (N > 0 && N % 1 == 0  )
```

Не имеет большого смысла и эквивалентно условию

```
 if (N > 0 )
```

так как переменная `N` объявлена как целочисленная переменная

```
int N, sum = 0, min = 0, sum_el_mat = 0, sum_el_mat2 = 0;
^^^^^^
```

а потому `N % 1` всегда будет равно 0, так как `1 * N` равно `N`. К тому же оператор `%` для чисел с плавающей запятой не определен в C++.

Что касается вашей просьбы помочь вам разбить программу на функции, то я покажу, как некоторые функции для вашей программы могут быть определены. Постарайтесь другие функции определить самостоятельно, используя нижеприведенную программу в качестве примера объявления функций.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include<ctime>

int ** create_matrix( int n )
{
    int **m = new int * [n];

    for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) m[i]= new int [n];

    return m;
}

void delete_matrix( int **m, int n )
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) delete [] m[i];
    delete [] m;
}

void initialize_matrix( int **m, int n )
{
    std::srand( ( unsigned int )std::time( nullptr ) );

    for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        for ( int j = 0; j < n; j++ ) m[i][j] = std::rand() % ( 2 * n + 1 ) - n;
    }
}

void output_matrix( int **m, int n )
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        for ( int j = 0; j < n; j++ )
        {
            std::cout << std::setw( 3 ) << m[i][j] << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}

long long int matrix_sum( int **m, int n )
{
    long long int sum = 0;

    for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        for ( int j = 0; j < n; j++ ) sum += m[i][j];
    }

    return sum;
}

int main() 
{
    const int N = 15;

    int **m = create_matrix( N );

    initialize_matrix( m, N );
    output_matrix( m, N );
    std::cout << std::endl;

    long long int sum = matrix_sum( m, N );

    std::cout << "The sum of all elements of the matrix is " << sum << std::endl;

    delete_matrix( m, N );

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль может выглядеть аналогично следующему выводу

```
-14 -12  11  14 -12   3  -4  -1 -11  -5  10  -9   6  -7  -2 
  7  10  15   2 -14   4  10   3 -10 -11 -14   0   7  12  -6 
 -5  13  -5 -12  11  -4   7 -11  10   9  -1   2  15 -13  10 
 -2  10   2  -5  -6   1  14 -14 -12 -14 -12 -11   1  10  14 
  8 -13  11 -15  -9   4  -4  13   8 -12   4 -10   5   3  -8 
 -3 -15  15  14  -5  -7   0  -9  -6   1  -7  -3   6   7  -9 
  4   0  -6  -2   0  -2 -14  10  -7  10  13  12  13   1  -1 
-11  13  -2 -11  12   6  -3  -6  13   5  10 -12  15  -2  10 
 -9 -15  -8  -2  -2   6  11  -1  -2 -12  -9  -5  13 -12   9 
 -4  -7   7   7  -5   1  -2   5   8  -7  -6   2  -6  -6  14 
-14  -2  14  -8   9  -4  13   2   8  -5   5  15   3   2 -15 
 -5  11  -9 -14   1   1   0  12 -11  -8 -13  -4   7  -4   3 
  5  -3 -15   1   4   7  12  -1  -7   3   7  11   2  -7  -5 
  0   3  -9   7   4   5 -10 -14   1  -6  -7   3   6  13  14 
 -7   1  -7  -8 -14  11  14  14  -8  -8   1  15 -13 -15  -8 

The sum of all elements of the matrix is -39
```

В программе для переменной `N` используется фиксированное значение.  Вы можете его задать после того, как пользователь введет свое значение, следующим образом

```
N += 15;
```

и далее работать только с переменной `N` без использования магического числа `15`.